# Incorrectly scheduled events remain in sidebar after being cancelled

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar, chat-event

For the second time recently, I've managed to schedule a chat event for the wrong time (the date defaults to tomorrow?!). Once I realised this, I unscheduled the event. However, there is still a link in the sidebar on the main site, several hours after I did so:

[image]

Comment: Caching maybe? :P

Comment: When did you unschedue it?

Comment: @shadow about 23.00 UTC last night, or thereabouts.

Comment: hmm.... so most likely a bug indeed.

Comment: @rene pls[.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=fredley+pls&user=27&room=35)

Comment: @badp I removed my comment so you can be pleased now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add an event via the `rooms/info` route on chat, a corresponding event is created in the site's community bulletin. If you then remove the event from the chat schedule, you need to remember to remove the corresponding community bulletin event manually by going to the (mod only) CB admin page.

I've modified the text of the confirm box that appears on deletion to remind you of this.

Comment: Isn't it better to have it done automatically?

Comment: The two events are not really linked together, it's a bit of a mess/dirty solution.

Comment: @ShadowWizard For the user: yes. For the dev: no.

Comment: Well, agree it's not important enough to be worth spending much time on. Anyway, @Sklivvz isn't it [tag:status-bydesign] since you didn't really fix anything?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did push a change, so I'd call it completed

Comment: @Sklivvz adding a reminder to perform this manually? Well... I don't agree but you call the shots. :-)